# Increasing and decreasing the volume of a jukebox(Actionscript 3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs5, volume

So I've been working on this jukebox assignment for some time now. And I've stumbled upon a problem related to changing the volume of the jukebox while playing the animation.
Here's the code I was trying to use:

```
var st:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform();
st.volume = 0.3;
SoundMixer.soundTransform = st;
```

And while this code in itself works perfectly fine, when I try to add it to my script, it has no effect on the volume level. (The code above is not added to the code below, as it didn't work)

Here is my script:

```
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
import flash.media.SoundTransform;

//Equalizer
var _sound1         :Sound          = null;
var _sound2         :Sound          = null;
var _sound3         :Sound          = null;
var _sound4         :Sound          = null;
var _sound5         :Sound          = null;
var _sound6         :Sound          = null;
var _sound7         :Sound          = null;
var _sound8         :Sound          = null;

//Volume

var _soundChannel   :SoundChannel   = null;
_soundChannel = new SoundChannel();

//Sanger
_sound1 = new Sound(new URLRequest("lyd1.mp3"));
_sound2 = new Sound(new URLRequest("lyd2.mp3"));
_sound3 = new Sound(new URLRequest("lyd3.mp3"));
_sound4 = new Sound(new URLRequest("lyd4.mp3"));
_sound5 = new Sound(new URLRequest("lyd5.mp3"));
_sound6 = new Sound(new URLRequest("lyd6.mp3"));
_sound7 = new Sound(new URLRequest("lyd7.mp3"));
_sound8 = new Sound(new URLRequest("lyd8.mp3"));


//Spille sanger
knapp1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, spill1);
knapp2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, spill2);
knapp3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, spill3);
knapp4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, spill4);
knapp5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, spill5);
knapp6.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, spill6);
knapp7.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, spill7);
knapp8.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, spill8);

function spill1(event:MouseEvent)
{
    SoundMixer.stopAll();
    _soundChannel = _sound1.play();
    skjermTekst.text = "Miami Nights - Ocean Drive";
}

function spill2(event:MouseEvent)
{
    SoundMixer.stopAll();
    _soundChannel = _sound2.play();
    skjermTekst.text = "Likelike - So Electric";
}

function spill3(event:MouseEvent)
{
    SoundMixer.stopAll();
    _soundChannel = _sound3.play();
    skjermTekst.text = "LazerHawk - Disco Planet";
}

function spill4(event:MouseEvent)
{
    SoundMixer.stopAll();
    _soundChannel = _sound4.play();
    skjermTekst.text = "Garth Knight - Silent Strike";
}

function spill5(event:MouseEvent)
{
    SoundMixer.stopAll();
    _soundChannel = _sound5.play();
    skjermTekst.text = "Mitch Murder - Terminator Theme";
}

function spill6(event:MouseEvent)
{
    SoundMixer.stopAll();
    _soundChannel = _sound6.play();
    skjermTekst.text = "Dynatron - Stars of the Night";
}

function spill7(event:MouseEvent)
{
    SoundMixer.stopAll();
    _soundChannel = _sound7.play();
    skjermTekst.text = "Electric Youth - The Best Thing";
}

function spill8(event:MouseEvent)
{
    SoundMixer.stopAll();
    _soundChannel = _sound8.play();
    skjermTekst.text = "Borgeoisie - Neon Black";
}

//Equalizer

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Update, false, 0, true)

function Update($e:Event):void
{
    _equalizer._eq1.gotoAndStop (Math.round(_soundChannel.leftPeak  * 3) ); 
    _equalizer._eq2.gotoAndStop (Math.round(_soundChannel.rightPeak * 5) );
    _equalizer._eq3.gotoAndStop (Math.round(_soundChannel.leftPeak * 7) ); 
    _equalizer._eq4.gotoAndStop (Math.round(_soundChannel.rightPeak * 9) );
    _equalizer._eq5.gotoAndStop (Math.round(_soundChannel.leftPeak * 11) ); 
    _equalizer._eq6.gotoAndStop (Math.round(_soundChannel.rightPeak * 13) );
    _equalizer._eq7.gotoAndStop (Math.round(_soundChannel.leftPeak * 15) );
    _equalizer._eq8.gotoAndStop (Math.round(_soundChannel.rightPeak * 17) );
    _equalizer._eq9.gotoAndStop (Math.round(_soundChannel.leftPeak  * 17) ); 
    _equalizer._eq10.gotoAndStop (Math.round(_soundChannel.rightPeak * 15) );
    _equalizer._eq11.gotoAndStop (Math.round(_soundChannel.leftPeak * 13) ); 
    _equalizer._eq12.gotoAndStop (Math.round(_soundChannel.rightPeak * 11) );
    _equalizer._eq13.gotoAndStop (Math.round(_soundChannel.leftPeak * 9) ); 
    _equalizer._eq14.gotoAndStop (Math.round(_soundChannel.rightPeak * 7) );
    _equalizer._eq15.gotoAndStop (Math.round(_soundChannel.leftPeak * 5) );
    _equalizer._eq16.gotoAndStop (Math.round(_soundChannel.rightPeak * 3) ); 
}
```

Now, with the volume snippet added the volume of the jukebox stays the same. Even if I change the st.volume = 0.3 to any other number between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

You could optimise your code greatly, and for this task you don't need SoundMixer, your sounds and `SoundChannels` are easily accessible. Main idea is to manage one at time `SoundChannel`:

```
const soundKey:String = "sound";
const soundNameKey:String = "soundName";
var sounds:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
var mainChannel:SoundChannel;
var volume:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform(1);

//"Bind" your buttons to the corresponding Sound description
sounds[knapp1] = {"sound": new Sound(new URLRequest("path")), "soundName": "Miami Nights - Ocean Drive"};
//Add all your sounds
//sounds[knapp8] = ...;

//Add all knapp buttons to the one container
//myKnappContainer.addChild(knapp1); ...

myKnappContainer.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var soundInfo:Object = sounds[e.target];
    if (soundInfo != null) {
        if (mainChannel != null) {
            //Stop previous sound
            mainChannel.stop();
        }

        //Start a new
        mainChannel = Sound(soundInfo[soundKey]).play();
        //Apply current volume
        mainChannel.soundTransform = volume;

        //Display sound name
        skjermTekst.text = soundInfo[soundNameKey];
    }
}
```